# PHP - strpos doesn't work

Tags: php, strpos

Here are examples of array

```
$array=array(array('#0kg - 50kg','Questions?','1|2'),
       array('Yes','','3|4'),
       array('#51kg - 100kg','Questions?','5|6'));
```

Here is function which i'm using to check if `#` is in string:

```
for ($i=0,$j=0;$i<count($array);$i++) {
  if (strpos($array[$i][0], '#') !== false) {
    echo preg_replace("/#/",'',$array[$i][0]);
    $j++;
  }
}
```

It doesn't show anything, there are no results.

Comment: What are the results and what is the expected result?

Comment: Don't check, just replace. If there's nothing to replace, nothing will happen.

Comment: just updated the question, sorry for that

Comment: Works fine if you **fix the incorrect variable name**: http://3v4l.org/Ns3qY

Comment: yea, i forgot to change `$finder` to `$array` to match this example, but it still doesn't work :/ I have 2 templates in wordpress (shared hosting package), in one it works, in the other one doesn't. Dont know what is going on

Answer (score 1):

This works as I would expect it, except `preg_replace` does not modify the given string but returns the new one. And if it's a single char str_replace will also fit your needs.

and

> Don't check, just replace. If there's nothing to replace, nothing will happen. –  @deceze

```
$array = array(
       array('#0kg - 50kg','Questions?','1|2'),
       array('Yes','','3|4'),
       array('#51kg - 100kg','Questions?','5|6')
);

foreach($array as &$elem) {
    $elem[0] = str_replace('#','',$elem[0]);
}
```

Comment: sorry, i missed echo. The thing is i want to display record only if `#` is in the string.